# Slow filtering using where clause on pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following where clause being used on a data frame and its taking a long time to complete. I'm reaching out for solutions to optimize the statement and make it faster.

Here is the code:

```
    t0 = time.time()
    df_test_app = df5.where(((df5.ID.isNotNull()) & (df5.XXX_VALUE.isNull()) & (df5.YYYY_TYPE.isNull())))
    print("Test COUNT = " + str(df_test_app.count()))
    print("time completed after where clause = " + str(time.time() - t0))

    #*** time completed after where clause = 931.6653690338135 ****
```

Also, just for fun, I wanted to calculate how much does a count statement take to execute, such as below and I was shocked by the number. 963 seconds. Can someone please explain why its taking that long for a count?

```
     t0 = time.time()
     df5 = df5.join(df_test_app, ["ID"], "left_anti")\
     .select(df5["*"])
     print("time completed after left anti join = " + str(time.time() - t0))
     # OK/good time
     # **** time completed after left anti join = 1.3093233108520508 ****

    t0 = time.time()
    print("Final count for df5 after excluding test applications = " + str(df5.count()))
    print("time completed for df5 final count = " + str(time.time() - t0))
    
    #*** time completed for df5 final count = 963.1556797027588
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `OK/good time` in your code comment is a lazy evaluated dataframe and not actually a job, hence it doesnot require much time. So timings look fine if the data is large as `count` shuffles data from all executers and brings it to the driver node

Comment: Thanks. I'm dealing with 400k records. Is there a way to speed up the where clause? 16 minutes for a where clause statement seems too much for 400k records.

Comment: `count()` is an expensive operation. In the real world, you would want to use count only for debugging purposes. I am not sure what you intend to do after the the filter operation. Not every action brings the data to the driver node.